# How to allow angular brackets <> without any characters between them using Regex?

Tags: java, regex

How to allow angular brackets <> without any characters/space between them using javax regex?Current pattern is like below:

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9\\s-_]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\\s-_]*$"
```

Comment: Can you show us some data you are trying to match?

Comment: Here is the data: "01 Customer Master - 04 <> Customer Incentives"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `|` token to create an alternative (match this *or* that).

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9\s-_]|<>)*[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9\s-_]|<>)*$
```

I changed both the `[A-Za-z0-9\s-_]+` at the start and end to `(?:[A-Za-z0-9\s-_]|<>)*`, which means "match 0 or more times `[A-Za-z0-9\s-_]` or `<>`".

`[A-Za-z0-9_]` can be simplified to `\w`, so a shorter version of the above would be:

```
^(?:[\w\s-]|<>)*[A-Za-z0-9](?:[\w\s-]|<>)*$
```